# $result->num_rows always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-num-rows

after reading tons of threads, tutorials and whatever - I feel like posting here and hope that someone can help me.
I tried out every advice I could get, but it's still not working.

Here is my code :

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(added,'%d.%M'), title FROM offers ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT ?, ?;";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
$stmt->bind_param ('ii',$lowlimit, $page);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $added, $title);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
... # some random output here
}
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
echo "c -> ". $count;exit;
```

I always get "c -> 0" ... but there IS output already ... so what am I doing wrong ? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `store_result()` method before accessing the `num_rows` property.

From a comment on [PHP manual documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php#71988):

> If you do not use `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`, and immediately call this function after executing a prepared statement, this function will usually return 0 as it has no way to know how many rows are in the result set as the result set is not saved in memory yet.
>
> `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` saves the result set in memory thus you can immedietly use this function after you both execute the statement AND save the result set.

Your code should look like:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $added, $title);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    # some random output here...
}

$count = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) You have to store it first.

```
$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows
```

Comment: Did it - but it didn't work THAT way - the Amal way helped me out tho

Comment: I was mearly showing the function rather than giving a copy/paste example for you to use.

Answer (score -1):

From the PHP manual, first comment https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php :

> Please be advised, for people who sometimes miss to read this important Manual entry for this function:
>
> If you do not use mysqli_stmt_store_result( ), and immediatley call
> this function after executing a prepared statement, this function will
> usually return 0 as it has no way to know how many rows are in the
> result set as the result set is not saved in memory yet.
>
> mysqli_stmt_store_result( ) saves the result set in memory thus you
> can immedietly use this function after you both execute the statement
> AND save the result set.
>
> If you do not save the result set but still want to use this function
> you have to actually loop through the result set one row at a time
> using mysqli_stmt_fetch( ) before using this function to determine the
> number of rows.
>
> A thought though, if you want to determine the number of rows without
> storing the result set and after looping through it, why not just
> simply keep an internal counter in your loop every time a row is
> fetched and save the function call.
>
> In short, this function is only really useful if you save the result
> set and want to determine the number of rows before looping through
> it, otherwise you can pretty much recreate its use like I suggested.